# Generate uncorrelated variables each well correlated with existing response variable

Tags: r, simulation

I want to generate two uncorrelated random variables (**x1,x2**) that show  specified Pearson correlations with an existing variable **y**, e.g:

- cor(**x1,y**)=0,4;
- cor(**x2,y**)=0,3;
- cor(**x1,x2**)=0,03.

So, I have continuous values, normally distributed, for **y** (using spatial interpolation technique) and now i want to generate simulated continuous values (e.g. Normal distribution) for two explanatory variables **x1** and **x2** using the correlation coefficients pointed above. 
I tried mvrnorm (MASS) and copula R packages, but i did not find the way to do what i want.

If one can help me getting there i will appreciate a lot. Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mvrnorm` function in the MASS package should be able to do this (the copula package as well, I am just less familiar with it).

What did you try and how did the results differ from what you expected?

Here is a quick `mvrnorm` example:

```
> ?MASS::mvrnorm
> library(MASS)
> 
> r <- cbind( c(1, 0.4, 0.3),
+             c(0.4, 1, 0.03),
+             c(0.3, 0.03, 1))
> 
> xy <- mvrnorm(n=100, mu=c(0,0,0), Sigma=r, empirical=TRUE )
> colnames(xy) <- c('y','x1','x2')
> 
> cor(xy)
     y   x1   x2
y  1.0 0.40 0.30
x1 0.4 1.00 0.03
x2 0.3 0.03 1.00
>
```

**Edit**

Here is one way with an existing y variable:

```
y <- rnorm(100)  # existing y

# generate x1 and x2, make sure y is first column
xy <- cbind( y, x1=rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100))

# center and scale
mns <- apply(xy, 2, mean)
sds <- apply(xy, 2, sd)

xy2 <- sweep(xy, 2, mns, FUN="-")
xy2 <- sweep(xy2, 2, sds, FUN="/")

# find existing correlations
v.obs <- cor(xy2)

# remove correlation
xy3 <- xy2 %*% solve(chol(v.obs))

# check
zapsmall(cor(xy3))

# new correlation

r <- cbind( c(1, 0.4, 0.3),
            c(0.4, 1, 0.03),
            c(0.3, 0.03, 1))

xy4 <- xy3 %*% chol(r)

# undo center and scale

xy4 <- sweep(xy4, 2, sds, FUN="*")
xy4 <- sweep(xy4, 2, mns, FUN="+")

#check
cor(xy4)
all.equal(y, xy[,1])
```

The `mvrnorm` function uses `svd` and Eigen values instead of `chol`.  You could also follow that code using your own y instead of random values for that part of the matrix.

Comment: @ManuelCR, using an existing y variable makes it a bit more difficult, see my edit above for one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you. 'mvrnorm' and 'copula' do the work, but with both you can't use your own data (variable y, in my case). My variable y has spatially dependent values (closer observations tend to be more similiar) and i want to preserve that. What i want is to add two other variables, to provide the complete dataset, where the correlation matrix is the one indicated.